# How to make this button layout look better

Tags: html, css

I need help with putting an image as the button as it won't work, and removing those lines in-between the buttons. If you can help please do. Thanks.

All the links, names, and files are for example purposes.

```css
.button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: url(button1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center;">
  <div id=button12>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
      <button class="button">Test 1</button>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/directory">
      <button class="button">Test 2</button>
    </a>
  </div>
  <a href="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=translate&t=chromentp&atb=v314-1&ia=web">
    <button class="button">Test 3</button>
  </a>
```

Comment: Don't use `buttons` inside `a` tags. What are you actually trying to do? Note "Permitted Content" : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 0):

You can add text-decoration:none on the Anchor to remove that line. I would however humbly recommend that you check out both HTML and CSS tutorials, and proceed to rewrite this code in another way. For instance, your `<H1>` had no closing, nor is it really for anything else than putting a header somewhere.

You can center buttons and divs without using h1, and you can style the anchors to look like buttons if that is what you'd like. The world is your domain.

```css
<style>
  .button{
    width:200px;
    height:80px;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:17px;
    margin:20px;
    background:url(button1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration:none;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Registrations site</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 style="text-align:center;">
    <div id=button12>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
        <button class="button">Test 1</button>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/directory">
        <button class="button">Test 2</button>
      </a>
    </div>
    <a href="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=translate&t=chromentp&atb=v314-1&ia=web">
      <button class="button">Test 3</button>
    </a>
  </h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap-all {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rowone {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.rowtwo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: url(button1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.button-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.img-wrapper {
  object-fit: fill;
  object-position: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.title-btn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  font-size: 12px;

}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="wrap-all">

      <div class="rowone">
        <div class="button-div" onclick="location.href='https://www.youtube.com/';">
          <img class="img-wrapper" src="http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c545.png" />
          <span class="title-btn">Youtube</span>
        </div>


        <div class="button-div" onclick="location.href='https://www.twitch.tv/directory/';">
          <img class="img-wrapper" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/twitch-app-logo-png-3.png" />
          <span class="title-btn">Twitch</span>
        </div>
        </div>
      

     <div class="rowtwo">
        <div class="button-div" onclick="location.href='https://duckduckgo.com/?q=translate&t=chromentp&atb=v314-1&ia=web';">
          <img class="img-wrapper" src="https://download.logo.wine/logo/DuckDuckGo/DuckDuckGo-Logo.wine.png" />
          <span class="title-btn">Duck</span>
        </div>
        </div>



    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I wanted to keep the layout before. The 2 buttons are on top and 1 below. If you can adjust to do that, that would be amazing.

Comment: you can check it, i have editted it

Comment: Javascript is not a great solution when it can be done with pure HTML. This is far from ideal in terms of SEO performance, accessibility, and just good old semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Use the right tool.

You can't have a button inside an anchor tag, it's invalid HTML. Don't use javascript when regular HTML will do.

Simply use a link and style it how you want. The key point is to make your `a` element `display:inline-block`, then give it button-like styling

```css
.button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 20px;
  /*Use Your image*/
  background: url("http://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/80");
  /*Make it an inline block*/
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 2px inset grey;
  /*remove default link styling*/
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  /*Vertiaclly align text - there are other ways but this is quick*/
  line-height: 80px;
  /*Making the text "readable"*/
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px white;
}

.button:hover {
  /*Throw some hover love*/
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px white;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center;">
  <div id=button12>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" class="button">Test 1</a>
    <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/directory" class="button">Test 2</a>
  </div>
  <a href="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=translate&t=chromentp&atb=v314-1&ia=web" class="button">Test 3</a>
</h1>
```

There are better ways to handle the layout, flex or css grid could be used here, but I'll just cover the basics for now.